# tkinter Checkbox set value if checked

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter as a front end for Cisco IOS automation, but the problem i face is i need to have check-boxes available, if checked the text associated to it should be passed to the Cisco IOS.
I tried to look into tkinter documentation but no luck.

```
Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
cv1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(SecondFrame,text='show cdp neighbor', variable=Var)
cv1.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='S', padx=5, pady=2)
```

Comment: I tried but Var catches only whether the checkbox is checked or not. i want the text that is associated with the checkbox. In my case 'show cdp neighbor' should be retrieved once selected.

Comment: Ah, my bad. So you are looking for `cv1["text"]` this value?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print(checkbutton.cget("text"))

checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text="Retrieve This Text")
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

checkbutton.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can use `.cget()` to retrieve the value of a `Tkinter` attribute. In the case above, you are printing the attribute `text` from the variable `checkbutton` which contains a predefined `Tkinter` `Checkbutton` element.

---

You can also do this directly from the `Checkbutton` by assigning a command to it. Meaning that the value would be received every time the `Checkbutton`s state updated

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command():
    print(checkbutton.cget("text"))

checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text="Retrieve This Text", command=command)

checkbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have one small doubt now i am able retrieve text with cget. i wrote a function which checks whether checkbox is called or not based on that append text. But I see text is not getting appended to the list.
    import tkinter
    command =[]
    def get_command():
        if c1==1:
            global command
            return lambda: command.append(c1.cget('text'))
    c1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(SecondFrame,text='show cdp 
    neighbor',command=get_command)
    c1.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='S', padx=5, pady=2)

Comment: Code doesn't format properly when put into a comment, can you instead describe what it is you are trying to achieve and I will see if I can help?

Answer (score 0):

> if checked the text associated to it should be passed to the Cisco IOS

Indicate that you need to **assign a variable** with `Widget.text` (here `Checkbutton.text`).

#### 1. Get `Widget.text` value

---

From [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/checkbutton.html):

> text: The label displayed next to the checkbutton. Use newlines ('\n') to display multiple lines of text.

To get this property:

- by `Checkbutton.cget()` (see answer above)
- directly access by `Checkbutton.text` or `Checkbutton["text"]`

Here, `cv1.text` or `cv1["text"]`

#### 2. Assign variable when checked

---

As using `Widget.bind()` to bind click event to `Checkbutton` instance is not working on my machine, here I

assign a callback function to `Checkbutton.command` and check by `Checkbutton.variable` if the button has been checked.

```
from Tkinter import *  # import tkinter if using python3
Var = IntVar(0)  # use IntVar to store stat whether the button is checked
# If use StringVar() for variable, set `Checkbutton.onstate` and `Checkbutton.offstate`
# see TkDocs above for details
def callback():  # command callback doesn't needed Event as argument
  if Var.get() == 0:  # not checked
    return  # do nothing
  global command
  command.append(cv1.text)
cv1 = Checkbutton(SecondFrame, text="show cdp neighbor", command=callback)
cv1.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky="S", padx=5, pady=2)
```

Here variable is not `Checkbutton.variable`:

> variable: The control variable that tracks the current state of the checkbutton; see Section 52, “Control variables: the values behind the widgets”. Normally this variable is an IntVar, and 0 means cleared and 1 means set, but see the offvalue and onvalue options above.

---

related questions:

- [Read status Checkbutton directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259379/read-status-checkbutton-directly)